# Insert multiple records in entity model in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

It's a winForm application and I'm using datagridview for insertion. I have multiple tables. This is what I'm doing to insert multiple data:

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var context = new EmployeeEntities())
    {
        EMPLOYEE emp = new EMPLOYEE();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvLoadTable.Rows)
        {
                emp.EMP_ID = int.Parse(row.Cells["EMP_ID"].Value.ToString());
                emp.DEPARTMENT= row.Cells["DEPARTMENT"].Value.ToString();
                //other columns in the same way, I want to change this
                context.EMPLOYEE.AddObject(emp);
                context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
 }
```

So, according to this way, I have to write code for each column for every table. Is there a better way to do this? Where the column name will be selected from the datagridview/ table column header and data type will be the type of column. Can anyone suggest anything, please?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see the need for any complex data manipulation in the question, I'd opt for using DataGridViews automatically generated from Data Sets.

Add a new Data Source to your project and wire it to your database. Make sure to include the needed tables in the Data Set. Once that is created, you can simply open the Data Sources Explorer and drag the necessary tables (under the Data Set you created) from the Data Sources Explorer to the form. The necessary Binding Source, Table Adapter, and Table Adapter Manager are generated for you automatically.

More detailed steps here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/how-to-bind-bindingnavigator-with-datagridview/

This may not work if your needs are more complex, but you may be able to customize it to suit your needs.